# Add payment after monthly schedule expired

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-5

I have two models, Payment and GroupStarts.

Payment has these fields:

> student_id, amount_to_pay, student_paid, date_paid, due_date, group_name

On GroupStarts are:

> group_name, group_start, group_end, group_status.

**This is how it should work:**

If payment is made for one month and it expires after month 1, it should add amount_to_pay to that for month 1 and if in month 2 student didn't paid nothing than we add + amount to pay, similar to: if student have to pay $10 and paid so owe is 0 but for next month he didn't paid so we add it to payment $10 if on month 3 he didn't paid we add $10 more to that amount.

How can I do that ?

This is code I tried:

```
private function getMonthlyUnpayments()
{

  $payments     = Payment::all();
  $unpayment    = 0;
  $totalPayment = 0;

        foreach ($payments as $key => $value) {
            $unpayment    += $value->amount_to_pay;
            $totalPayment += $value->student_paid;          
        }    

        $studentsAllU     = Student::where('is_canceled', '=', 0)->get();
        $groupAllU        = Gstart::where('group_status', '=', 0)->get();
        $studentGroupAllU = [];
        foreach ($studentsAllU as $key => $value) {

            foreach ($groupAllU as $keys => $valu) {
              foreach ($value->payment as $paymentID) {
                 if ($value->group_id == $valu->group_name) {
                         $studentGroupAllU[] = ['name' => $value->full_name,  'student_id' => $value->id, 'gr_id' => $value->group_id, 'paid' => $paymentID->student_paid, 'to_pay' =>  $paymentID->amount_to_pay, 'due_date' => $paymentID->due_date, 'group_ends' => $valu->group_end];
                      }  
              }                       
                }            
        }
function nb_mois($from, $to)
{
     $fromYear = date("Y", strtotime($from));
        $fromMonth = date("m", strtotime($from));
        $toYear = date("Y", strtotime($to));
        $toMonth = date("m", strtotime($to));
        if ($fromYear == $toYear) {
            return ($toMonth-$fromMonth)+1;
        } else {
            return (12-$fromMonth)+1+$toMonth;
        }
}

function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo)
{
    $aryRange=array();

    $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),     substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
    $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),     substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));

    if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom)
    {
        array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
        while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo)
        {
            $iDateFrom+=86400; 
            array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
        }
    }
    return $aryRange;
}
        $dtArr = [];
        $incrementer = 0;
            $inc = 0;

        foreach ($studentGroupAllU as $key => $value) {

                if ($value['group_ends'] >= $value['due_date']  || $value['paid'] < $value['to_pay']) {
                  if ($value['paid'] < $value['to_pay']) {
                    $incrementer += ($value['to_pay'] - $value['paid']);
                  }
                  else {
                     $incrementer += ($value['to_pay']);
                  }

                      $dtArr[] = ['days_left' => count(createDateRangeArray($value['due_date'], $value['group_ends'])), 'group_id_d' => $value['gr_id'], 'paid' => $value['paid'], 'to_pay' => $value['to_pay'], 'student_id' => $value['student_id'], 'owe' => ($inc +=($value['to_pay'] - $value['paid'])), 'dates' =>  createDateRangeArray($value['due_date'], $value['group_ends']),'dates_fron_last_payment' =>  createDateRangeArray($value['due_date'], Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')), 'days_fron_last_payments' => count(createDateRangeArray($value['due_date'], Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')))];

                }
                    $inc = 0;
        }

function uniqueAssocArray($array, $uniqueKey) {
      $arr = array();

      foreach($array as $key => $item)
      {
         $arr[$item[$uniqueKey]][$key] = $item;

      }

      ksort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
      return $arr;
}
$dd = uniqueAssocArray($dtArr, 'group_id_d');
$tpStudentGr = 0;
        // dd($dtArr);
      foreach ($dtArr as $key => $value) {
           foreach ($value['dates'] as $k => $val) {

            if ($val == Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $val)->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d') && $val <= Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d')) {

         if ($value['paid'] <  $value['to_pay']){

                      $tpStudentGr += ($value['to_pay'] - $value['paid'] + $value['to_pay']);                  

                }
            if ($value['paid'] ==  $value['to_pay']){
                          $tpStudentGr += $value['to_pay'];
                }    
            }    
          }
          if ($value['days_left'] > 0) {

          }        
      }     
           $tpStudentGr = $unpayment - $totalPayment;
           return $tpStudentGr;    
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're having with the code you wrote.

Comment: You are asking: "how can I do that?" SO is not a place to ask people to write code for you, it is a place to get help with problems that occur when you write code. Therefor, provide us with the errors that occur in your current code, and we will explain to you why you get those errors.

Comment: Issue is that when I want to get for example total owe for two months of expiration its like duplicating amount.